# Authentication from app before LAContext

Tags: ios, xcode, lacontext

I working on app in which I want to integrate Local Authentication from app, I used `LAContext` and working fine successfully.

As we know passcode was with iPhone from beginning and `LAContext` Introduced from **iOS8**.

- I want to know how can we use Passcode or authentication within app before **iOS8** ? or we can't ?

I know the fact that there are very few devices those are on earlier **iOS8** in market, but I want to quite sure about my app's least version support.

Looking for suggestion and help. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to support iOS 7 now in a new app is a waste of time and effort. Even supporting iOS 8 or even 9 with a new app now is almost pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, but it might be a client's demand in this case, who may possesses outdated devices.

Comment: @maddy I already gave that answer but "the4kman" is absolutely right on this. So anyone know ?